# Call actions in componentdidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to update state in `componentdidUpdate` and for this I want to call a function but the console shows a typeError:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.props.updateMarketCap is not a function

### I have imported that func in my file..below is an example:

```
import { fetchMarketCap } from '../Actions/Marketcap';
import { updateMarketCap } from '../Actions/Marketcap';
componentDidMount(){
    // setInterval(this.props.fetchMarketCap(), 3000);
    this.props.fetchMarketCap();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.props.fetchMarketCap();
    }, 20000);
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    const prev = prevProps.marketcap.map((coin, i) => (
       <tr key={this.props.marketcap[i].CoinInfo.Id}>
            <td className="crypt-up"><b>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</b></td>
            <td className={coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE < this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'crypt-up' : (coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE > this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'crypt-down' : 'equal')}>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</td>
        </tr>
    ));

    this.props.updateMarketCap(prev);
}
```

And at the end file:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   marketcap: state.marketcap.coins
});
export default connect ( mapStateToProps, { fetchMarketCap } )(Marketcap);
```

### And the action function is

```
export const updateMarketCap = (newData) => dispatch => {
   dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_MARKET_CAP,
      payload: newData
   })
}
```

I have imported Action types and other things properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something has to be wrong in connect function i think. The mapDispatchToProps is not defined properly and this is the wire that connect your actions imported with the props you are trying to call.

```
mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchMarketCap ,
    updateMarketCap 
};
```

Comment: I have `mapstatetoprops` here..I have updated question.Look at that

Comment: Ok but you are not including the updateMarketCap into the actions to connect i think you should include that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have componentDidUpdate return a true or false, so in your situation maybe something like.  I'm assuming you have a mapDispatchToProps on this page right?

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){

```
if(prevProps!==prevState){
let marketCap
marketCap = (
 const prev = prevProps.marketcap.map((coin, i) => (
   <tr key={this.props.marketcap[i].CoinInfo.Id}>
        <td className="crypt-up"><b>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.MKTCAP}</b></td>
        <td className={coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE < this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'crypt-up' : (coin.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE > this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE ? 'crypt-down' : 'equal')}>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}>{this.props.marketcap[i].DISPLAY.USD.PRICE}</td>
    </tr>
));
}

this.props.updateMarketCap(prev);
}
```

)

Then in your return statement throw {marketCap} in where you want it

Comment: I assumed that he has a mapstatetodispatch, butyeah that  could be causing an issue, we need to it.

Comment: I have `mapstatetoprops` here..I have updated question.Look at that